# Try use Cordova plugins in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, iframe, plugins

I'm working with Cordova loading a HTML in a iframe. All work fine but I need access to the plugins in the original HTML.
The original code is like this

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail);
```

When I load that HTML in a iframe I need make this

```
parent.navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail);
```

This code work but I really need don't change the original code. Somebody know how I can use cordova plugins in a iframe ?

Comment: Are you loading the same page in the iframe? I mean, is the Original code and the iframe page's code the same?

Comment: if you dont want to use window parent and want the iframe to be self-sufficient, then you need to include all the necessary resources (cordova, plugins, etc...) in the html loaded inside the iframe. personlly I ll just put a condition in the code and keep it dry `(self==top) ? navigator.camera : parent.navigator.camera`

Comment: @Mnavarro Can you green-check my answer please ?

Answer (score 3):

Add the cordova.js link to the html file being loaded into your ifame.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that, and the global variables are not available on the `window` inside the iframe (and the onReady event doesn't fire either).

Comment: @Paul what version of cordova are you using and on what device?

Comment: on iOS 8.4 on an iPhone 6 using ionic 1.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Code in your iFrame **exactly like in your main HTML, like if main HTML doesnt exist.**

For the iFrame `onReady` fail: use rather `load()`

```
$('iframe#my_iFrame_id').load(function() {
        //code here...
    });
```

**EDIT**
What is a `Cordova` plugin ? It is a bunch of **native code** (Obj-C for `iOS`, `Java` for `Android`, etc.), which is called by JS 'bridge' functions. *Note: You can do your own plugin, btw, quite easily if you know coding native - moreover it is interesting to do cross-code JS/native.*

Well, The plugin native code does care nothing about your iFrame... it executes native stuff and give you the power to input it, and get output. There is no use IN an iFrame, but FROM an iFrame. So... it is so simple... you shall code in your iFrame like you would do in the main HTML. Add JS (cordova, etc) and do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**hello try this one**

---

> `<iframe src="map.html" seamless="" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>`

---

and add cordova.js in your index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.postMessage and window.onMessage for cross communication between iframe and its parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onmessage

https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299

https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication